# Add a class file to a project class loader

Tags: java, classloader

I have managed to add a custom class to a user's project(in Blue J).  I am developing inside eclipse.

I was just wondering if anyone could help with the theory of what to do after adding the java file to the project directory and then compiling it.

I have a class file and a java file inside the user's project but I assume that I need to add it to the class loader being used in BlueJ.

I have tried a number of ways but keeping getting `ClassNotFoundException`

My best attempt so far is:

```
/** 
 * @param cLoader the bluej class loader inside eclipse
 * @param packageName the name of the package the bluej project belongs to
 */
public void addURL(ClassLoder cLoader, String packageName)
    {
        try
        {
            ClassLoader classLoader = cLoader;
            classLoader.loadClass(packageName);
        }
        catch(ClassNotFoundException e)
        {
            //do something
        }
    }
```

Comment: `loadClass` takes a class name as argument, not a package name, and your comment is broken so I'm surprised you haven't gotten a syntax error.  Are you sure that this version of your code is what is actually running?

Comment: the comment was posted in here as an add on just so you could see what was trying to be done, not representitive of my actual project

Comment: I edited the comment so others aren't confused.  Please post the value of `packageName` for which you are getting the error.

Comment: And what is `cLoader`'s parent classloader?